# Change Encoding in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf

*Theoretical question :*

Let's say there is one source which knows only how to transmit `ASCII` chars. (0..127)

And let's say there is an endpoint which receives these chars .

Can the endpoint decode those chars as utf8 ?

```
    ascii chars
        ...
        ...
         |
         |
         V

    read as utf ?
```

Something like this pseudo code :

```
    var txt="אבג";
    var _bytes=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txt);   <= it wont recognize [א] here
    ...transmit...
    var myUtfString=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(getBytesFromWire();  <= some magic has to be done here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possible, but not using UTF8.
UTF8 works by encoding multibyte characters into sequences of bytes that are between 128 and 255.
Your ASCII protocol will not be able to transmit those bytes.

Instead, you need some mechanism to store arbitrary Unicode codepoints or bytes in pure ASCII text:

- You can encode the Unicode text using any encoding to get a stream of (non-ASCII) bytes, then transmit those bytes using Base64 encoding
- You can use the [UTF7 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) to encode Unicode codepoints using pure ASCII characters.
  This will be substantially more space-efficient than Base64 if your text is mostly ASCII.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: UTF7 is a Unicode encoding just like UTF8.  However, unlike UTF8, it only uses pure-ASCII characters (or rather, bytes). You can simply use the `Encoding.UTF7` class.

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask( your edit) who is more verbose over the network. base64 vs utf7.....

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It depends on the distribution of characters.

Comment: UTF-7 uses base64 encoding.

Comment: I don't understand something : `Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes("1")` is `49`.  and `Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes("1א")` is `49 43 66 100 65 45` it is not like base64 where each char is fixed length (4). so how can the decoder know how to parse it ? it could decide to do `49 43` and `66 100 65 45` or other variations... can you explain ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: See the Wikipedia article, which explains how the encoding works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7  The base64 sections is surrounded by `+...-`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var txt = "אבג";
var str = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt)); //<--ASCII
//Transmit
var txt2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(str));
```